# How are DNS name-servers for a TLD updated when a new domain is registered?

Tags: domain-name-system

Let's say I have registered new domain mydomain.com with a domain registrar like Godaddy.

When I dig for my domain, I see the following section:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.com.       3079    IN  NS  nsXX.domaincontrol.com.
mydomain.com.       3079    IN  NS  nsXX.domaincontrol.com.
```

This indicates that the authoritative servers for mydomain.com are the nsXX.domaincontrol.com servers, which (according to info out there) are godaddy-owned name servers.

I would like to better understand how the .com TLD servers are updated to know the authoritative name-servers for a newly registered domain? Specifically:

1. Does this involve a zone file update for the .com TLD? If so what
   kind of entry is made there?
2. Is there only one zone file for the .com TLD?
3. What is the mechanism by which the update is made? Is there any API integration between a registrar like Godaddy and the TLD server
   to make such entries? Or does the registrar publish such updates by
   some other mechanism?
4. At the registrar end, is a separate zone file created and maintained for mydomain.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, the TLD updates their zone to include your name servers, so that a resolver knows where to go next. When a recursive resolver looks up a record, it first goes to the root `.` to get the name servers for `com.`, then it asks those servers for the name servers for `mydomain.com.` which it then asks for the record, for example `www.mydomain.com.`. Or if it's a delegated subdomain, it might get another set of name servers, and so and so forth.
2. Yes, in theory there's only one single zone file, it's however replicated to a lot of different servers globally.
3. Larger TLDs and registrars use an API call to notify the TLD operator of any new registrations and changes. In fact almost every TLD has some sort of API, but smaller registrars still do manage things manually (usually smaller outfits that don't mainly deal in domains, but offer it as a part of their services)
4. If the registrar offers DNS services, they might automatically create a zone for your domain so you can get started (this is what GoDaddy seems to have done), and as such they've registered their servers as the name servers for `mydomain.com.` with the .com. TLD. However, some registrars don't offer these services, so they'll just register whatever name servers you specify.

There are some TLDs that let the end customer register with them directly, for example the .fi. TLD used to allow this, but has since demanded that end customers go through a registrar for some reason.

Comment: About 3: almost all the industry (but there are notable exceptions like `de`)  uses EPP (see RFC 5730 and following). This is an XML based protocol for provisioning objects so it is used between registries and registrars. And there are indeed still registries accepting direct end customers, like `de`. There are also some TLDs with no registrars.